# Qt: Issuing a message before emitting a signal

Tags: qt, slot, qmessagebox, qradiobutton

Brief description of my application and my question:

In a QTabWidget I have several groupBoxes containing each 2 QRadioButtons.
E.g.
Select Menu (groupBox): (RadioButton:) A (RadioButton:) B

At one point of time, only one Menu can be active. 
Both radioButtons are connected to each othe -> 
When I click radioButton A and set it true, radioButton B is automatically set false - and the other way round.

When trying to change the menu setting, before a click signal is emitted, I would like to issue a QMessageBox Warning "Are you sure you want to change the menu? This can cause severe damage to your device." -Yes/No.

When clicking Yes, I would like to change the menue setting. When clicking No, I would like everything to remain as before.

The only problem I have is: When issuing the QMessageBox in the on_radio_button_toggled slot, the radioButton state has already changed to true.
Even if I change the state in the slot again and correct them, it looks like the state has already changed when the pop up message shows up. I don't want that because that implies that the state of the menue has already changed.

Where or How can I let a QMessageBox pop up before emitting the  actual signal slot - when clicking the radio Button?

Thank you very much for your help.

Update:
I have now implemented an eventFilter as recommended. Here is my source code:

```
ui->radioButtonMenu1->installEventFilter(this);
ui->radioButtonMenu2->installEventFilter(this);
```

SubmenuOne is a QWidget. It is integrated into the MainWindow by a QTabWidget (via placeholder).

```
bool SubmenuOne::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
{
QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
reply= QMessageBox::question(this,tr("WARNING"),tr("Changing the settings   may cause severe damage to your device! Please confirm your decision."),QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
{

//QMouseEvent *mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
   //keyEvent->accept();
   //event->accept();
   qDebug("Yes.");
    return false;
}
else
{
    qDebug("No.");

     return true;
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);` Declare event filter in your window, then instal event filter to every radiobutton like this: `radioButton1->installEventFilter(this);`. Then at eventFilter check event type: `if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)` and show your `QMessageBox`. Then you can accept event and return `true` or `false` depending on user choise.

```
bool SubmenuOne::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
  if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
  {
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply= QMessageBox::question(this,tr("WARNING"),tr("Changing the settings   may cause severe damage to your device! Please confirm your decision."),QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);

    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        static_cast<QRadioButton*>(obj)->setChecked(True);
    }
    event->accepted();
    return true;
  }
  return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event); //you forget this. QMainWindow is just base class of your SubmenuOne.
}
```

Comment: I have one little remaining question. I have installed the filter to the radio buttons and have written the eventFilter function. But if I click Yes, the value does not change yet. I am stuck. How can I connect the boolean return value of this function to the radioButton? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When you return `true` it means that event filtered. When you return `false` event not filtered, so radio button will change state. For more information about event filter read Qt documentation

Comment: I still have not found the solution for this. I have read through QObject and QEvent classes in the doucmentation more than once - but am not able to trace my mistake. Now when I click YES, the radioButton is marked blue, but it is not checked. If I press No, it is not marked. This implies that my eventFilter works properly; but yet the mouseClick does not trigger the radioBox slot. What a riddle. I do use accepted() functions in the eventFilter. Anybody a clue?

Comment: If you want check radio button then you should not call `accepted()` on event.

Comment: I deleted the accepted() - but nothing changes??? Slowly but surely this is getting really confusing. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Can you update your question with code of your eventFilter?

Comment: I don't know why but I get the compiler error "cannot call member function 'virtual bool QObject::eventFilter(QObject *; QEvent *)" ... it is not a typo, probably I did not understand what you meant in the comment -> regarding     return QMainWindow:: eventFilter (obj,event);

Comment: What is parent class of your `SubmenuOne`? Just replce `QMainWindow` with it.

Comment: Now it compiles, but the radioButtons are still only marked not checked. Thank you again for your patience!!!

Comment: Ok, then we can just check it right at event filter. See my updated unswer

Comment: YEAH!! That was it :) Thank you very much for your help!! Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Please don't forget that user can check radio button without mouse using keyboard. So you may want to filter more events. But I think you can do it now by yourself ;)